# Users logging into Windows 2008 R2 Server?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, login, users

We've found a bunch of users in our server's "Users" folder.

Not entirely sure how this happened, or what is going on.

This server is also our front end mail server (Exchange 2010)

We have theories, but nothing to really back them up.

Each local profile is about 2.75 mb, minus those of the admins.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The local profiles are created on your CAS server to house the individuals' OWA preferences.  They can be safely ignored.

Comment: The weird thing is that it looks like this started some time late 2010. Was there an update that did this? Do you know why there are only newer accounts vs the older ones that don't show up here in the Users folder?